# got error "variable used within it's own initial value"

Tags: ios, swift

when i am trying to run this code i got error "variable used within it's own initial value" . what cause this error ?

```
var pagetitle = ""
var alertActionButtons = [UIAlertAction]()
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: pagetitle, style: .Default) { action in
    self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) {
        self.unitDetailProtocolVar!.closeUnitDetail()
    }
}
alertActionButtons.append(okAction)
self.alert = self.controllerUtil.customAlert(pagetitle, buttons: alertActionButtons, alertMessage: alertMessage)
```

Comment: I see you edited the question to include the missing curly brace. Is it still giving you the same error? If so, check for a recursive method call. Is this code written within dismissViewControllerAnimated or closeUnitDetail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error itself means that you are trying to use a variable to initialize itself.

In your case it's just a missing bracket, causing code to be misaligned. This is how your code looks like:

```
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: pagetitle, style: .Default){ action in
    self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { ()->Void in
        self.unitDetailProtocolVar!.closeUnitDetail()
    })

    alertActionButtons.append(okAction)
    self.alert = self.controllerUtil.customAlert(pagetitle, buttons: alertActionButtons, alertMessage: alertMessage)
}
```

and you can see that `okAction` is used in this line:

```
alertActionButtons.append(okAction)
```

The missing bracket in your code is in the closure passed to the `UIAlertAction`:

```
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: pagetitle, style: .Default){ action in
    self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { ()->Void in
        self.unitDetailProtocolVar!.closeUnitDetail()
    })
} // <-- this is missing

alertActionButtons.append(okAction)
self.alert = self.controllerUtil.customAlert(pagetitle, buttons: alertActionButtons, alertMessage: alertMessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the curly brace before calling alertActionButtons.append(okAction). Therefore, it thinks you're trying to use okAction within it's own assignment block.

Corrected Code:

```
var pagetitle = ""
var alertActionButtons:[UIAlertAction] = [UIAlertAction]()
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: pagetitle, style: .Default){action in
    self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {()->Void in
        self.unitDetailProtocolVar!.closeUnitDetail()
    });
} // <- Added missing curly brace     
alertActionButtons.append(okAction)
self.alert = self.controllerUtil.customAlert(pagetitle, buttons: alertActionButtons, alertMessage: alertMessage)
```