# How to access the variable inside the closure which is passed as an argument during it's initialization?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView inside the XIB file, which is declared as container view. Inside the container view I am trying to add the view of libraryViewController. Once, I select the image from library view controller, I want to remove the libraryViewController's view from the SuperView. I am using the following link as reference to implement this functionality: https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController

```
let libraryViewController = ALCameraViewController(croppingEnabled: croppingEnabled, 
    allowsLibraryAccess: libraryEnabled){ (image) -> Void in
                        self.imageView.image = image
                        libraryViewController.view.removeFromSuperview() //error 

                    }
 containerView.addSubview(libraryViewController.view)
```

I get an error(Variable used within it's own initial value) when trying to access the libraryViewController from inside the closure.
How can I access the libraryViewController from the closure?

Comment: change let libraryViewController to var instead. does that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [got error "variable used within it's own initial value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139112/got-error-variable-used-within-its-own-initial-value)